# RoR: how can I seperate a page on my website into two large columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to make a vertical line going through the middle of the site and then have content on either side. How can I use CSS or ruby? to do this? I am not sure which one I would need and where I would put it. Also, what is the best resource for learning the syntax of the ruby on rails views/CSS stuff. It seems that rubyonrails.org doesn't have much documentation on that (they mostly explain the models and controllers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you start with something like: https://github.com/softmachine/rails-bootstrap

They provide a link to http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ which has plenty of documentation.

The next step, would be to ask a more specific question related to the exact problem you're having.

From your description it sounds like you need css, and depending on the nature of of the information you want to display, you might need to use ruby/rails to make it happen. Most likely, you could just use css.

see: http://jsfiddle.net/aTUq8/

Comment: how can I make it more specific? I am not having a problem yet because I don't know what to try. I want the website to have content on both sides of a vertical line kind of like a newspaper with two columns

Comment: @BigBoy1337, I've added a quick and dirty example of what the css and html might look like.